# Laravel Mail not working while notifications are

Tags: laravel, email

I have a problem with sending emails in laravel,

Emails are not sent using Mail class but notifications are working as well.

Here is examples of code I tested:

```
Mail::raw('Message to send', function($mail){
        $mail->from('backend@mysite.com', 'mysite');
        $mail->to('admin@mysite.com')
            ->subject('Mail object');
    });


Mail::send('emails.welcome', ['content' => 'Welcome'], function($mail){
        $mail->from('backend@mysite.com', 'mysite');
        $mail->to('admin@mysite.com')
            ->subject('Mail object');
    });
```

in emails/welcome.blade.php there is only one variable {{ $content }}.

But this is working:

```
$user->notify(new WelcomeEmail());
```

I m using the latest laravel 5.6 and mailtrap

Comment: Do this in terminal - `tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log`, then run the mail method again and check what the error is.

Comment: You should pass data to your mail `$content` otherwise how you want retrieve it in emails? Look at laravel site samples.  `$content = welcome` then `function($mail, $content)`